# Oracle Instant with LDAP gives error ORA-12154

Tags: database, oracle

**Help connecting to LDAP db w/ Oracle Instant Client**

**Test environment:** a Mac connecting to an Oracle 12c database

**Client software:** Oracle Instant Client

**Oracle DB name (example):** oid.db.example.com

**DB alias:** mydb

**DP port:** 4000

**DB connectivity:** LDAP via OID

**Service Name:** myservice

**LDAP stuff:** cn=utility

The LDAP string that works in Oracle SQL Developer:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid.db.example.com:4000/myservice,cn=utility

**[Environment Variables]**

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/Applications/Oracle_Instant 

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Oracle_Instant

export TNS_ADMIN=/Applications/Oracle_Instant/network/admin

export ORACLE_ADMIN=${TNS_ADMIN}
```

**## Settings in network/admin/ ##**

[ldap.ora]

```
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE=oid

DIRECTORY_SERVERS=(oid.db.example.com:4000)

DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT="cn=utility"
```

[sqlnet.ora]

```
names.directory_path = (LDAP, HOSTNAME)

names.default_domain = WORLD

trace_level_client = OFF

sqlnet.expire_time = 30
```

[tnsnames.ora]

```
mydb = (description=

    (address_list=

        (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = oid.db.example.com)(port = 4000))

)

(connect_data =

    (SID=myservice

        (SERVER = DEDICATED)

)
```

*Command I tested with, but got an error:*

./sqlplus myusername/mypassword@mydb

**Error I got:**

```
./sqlplus username/password@mydb
```

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Nov 18 19:01:23 2019

Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: What does `tnsping mydb` give you?

Comment: Oracle Instant Client does not include tnsping, and I do not know where to get the Linux binary.